# Core-plot, UIView, and a UILable results in upside-down text

Tags: uiview, uilabel, core-plot

I've got a core-plot graph that I display on a view and I need to add some UILabels to the bottom of the view.  So, I found out that the 0,0 is in the lower left for this view instead of upper left.  I believe this is due to the Quartz framework that core plot uses.  When I add the UILables, the text in them is upsidedown.  I need to rotate the text 180 degrees around the x-Axis in the middle of the text box.  Can someone provide me with code that will do this?

Here's the code I have to create the UILabels:

```
int XLen = (self.view.frame.size.width-10) /3;
int YLen = 20;
int XPos = 10+([self.AllTheProbes count] % 3)*XLen;
int YPos = (([self.AllTheProbes count] / 3)+1)*YLen;
UILabel *myLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(XPos, YPos, XLen, YLen)];
myLabel.text = aProbe.sUserAssignedName;
myLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Courier" size: 10.0];
    myLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
[self.view addSubview:myLabel];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't add subviews to the Core Plot hosting view. Add them to the parent view so they're siblings of the Core Plot view.

Comment: Being new to iPhone programming and Core-Data, I'm not sure how to add them as siblings.  here's the code I'm using to add the graph to the self view:'code'    //Set up the graph space
    graph = [[CPXYGraph alloc] initWithFrame: self.view.bounds];
    hostingView = (CPGraphHostingView *)self.view;
    hostingView.hostedGraph = graph;

Comment: Make your top-level view (`self.view`) a standard UIView (or other view class). Add your hosting view and labels as subviews of that view.

Comment: The top level view is a CPGraphHostingView and when I change it to UIView, the app crashes at the last line in this set of code:     //Set up the graph space
    graph = [[CPXYGraph alloc] initWithFrame: self.view.bounds];
    hostingView = (CPGraphHostingView *)self.view;
    hostingView.hostedGraph = graph;

Comment: Try `hostingView = [(CPGraphHostingView *)[CPGraphHostingView alloc] initWithFrame:/* the frame */]; [self.view addSubview:hostingView]; hostingView.hostedGraph = graph;`.

Comment: That seems to have fix the upside down, but now my graph doesn't appear.  I'm going to check some things with the core-plot group on Google to look into that.  Thanks for the help Eric.

Comment: Thanks! Had accidentally added as a subview in IB. You know, that annoying thing where you drag a view to move it and it puts it as a subview of another view..